# Square brackets syntax in class inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found this code and I am not that familiar with type hints as I understand that `SomeClass` inherits the `Car` class? but why it is like this `ReadSearch[Car]`, can someone explain this kind of syntaxes when using square brackets in class inheritance?

```
from attrs import frozen
from read import ReadSearch


@frozen(kw_only=True)
class Car:
    id: str
    name: str


@frozen
class SomeClass(ReadSearch[Car]):
    id: str


read file. that imported above

from typing import Generic, TypeVar


Result = TypeVar("Result")

class ReadSearch(Generic[Result]):
```

Comment: `ReadSearch` is imported from module `read`.  Presumably, `ReadSearch[Car]` is a dictionary lookup that returns a class object, which then serves as the class from which `SomeClass` inherits.  This is an unusual approach, but not any new syntax.

Comment: `SomeClass` inherits from `ReadSearch` - specifically, a specialized version of `ReadSearch` in which every reference to the type variable `Result` is replaced by `Car`.  Other specializations of `ReadSearch` could exist that work with some other class.  This is just a more advanced form of type hints like `list[int]` that declare that the list will hold only integers.

Answer (score 2):

In this case `ReadSearch` is inheriting from `Generic`, which [by looking in the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/typing.py#L1788) has a `__class_getitem__` (see [this pep](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/#class-getitem) for more details). Python exposes `__class_getitem__` as a `[]` operator on the class, i.e.:

```py
class Foo:
   def __class_getitem__(cls, i):
       return ["foo"]*i
```

would mean the following would be returned:

```py
Foo[1]
>>> ["foo"]

Foo[2]
>>> ["foo", "foo"]
```

In terms of what this all means in your case - it really doesn't mean anything- inheriting a typehint in this way doesn't offer any concrete features- and if you've read the docs and don't understand the hint then it's not likely a very good typehint!